# Why are my child routes not shown in nested router outlet?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, router-outlet

I am trying to set up a simple Angular application with a fixed frame component, which shows one out of a couple of content components depending on the route - like this:

[image: page structure]

So, if the route is, for instance, `#/a`, content A should be displayed, and if it is `#/b`, content B should be displayed. (Note that this URL structure is a hard requirement. That is, no additional path level is permitted before the content child route.)

I thought I could solve this by having a frame component with a `<router-outlet>`:

```html
<p>Welcome!</p>

<router-outlet name="content"></router-outlet>
```

Then, I thought I could specify the content components in child routes:

(from my `app.module.ts`:)

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: FrameComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'a',
        component: ContentAComponent,
        outlet: 'content',
      },
      {
        path: 'b',
        component: ContentBComponent,
        outlet: 'content',
      },
    ],
  },
];
// ...
  RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
```

For some reason, when I navigate to route `/a` and `/b`, the text "Welcome" is displayed, but the content components (whose templates would say "Content A" and "Content B", respectively) appear to be missing.

I have also tried removing the outlet names both in `frame.component.html` and in the routes, but to no avail.

I have created this on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-urtqe6?file=src/app/app.module.ts).

**What am I missing here?**

Answer (score 1):

You are using `secondary` route but navigating to it by "primary" way xD.

`/a, /b` is for primary route
`(secondary_route_name:path` is for secondary route

So in your case, the link should be: **url.com/(content:a)**

Comment: I see. What do I have to do so I can navigate by "primary" route way then? The URL looking like `url.com/a` is a fixed requirement for me.

Comment: that `url.com/a` is the way to visit primary route

Comment: my bad, I interpreted your last question wrongly. I don't know the answer for that question but I think it's not possible. As you have to have a way to differentiate between 2 routes, if you give me just one link: url.com/a, I wouldn't know if you want to go to the primary or the second route. So different urls is needed

Comment: I am not sure what to make of that. I do not insist to use a primary or a secondary route; I'll use whatever fits the task at hand. However, what I do want to achieve is that if `url.com/#/a` or `url.com/#/b` are opened, I will *always* end up on `FrameComponent`, with `ContentAComponent` or `ContentBComponent` shown inside that frame according to the current route.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-njtthu?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: Not quite, I'm afraid - now the content components are included directly in the app component, rather than in the frame.

Comment: not really, you can just move the part into the FrameComponent. What important is you place the content within the router-outlet, so it render every time for every route, exactly what you need